# Active Keyframe in the Graph Editor

Tags: python, animation, keyframes, graph-editor

How does one get the Graph Editor's active keyframe in Python? I know how to get selected keys using `select_control_point`, but I cannot find the `active` property in the [API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Keyframe.html).

There is also `bpy.context.active_editable_fcurve`, but [FCurve](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html?highlight=active_object#bpy.context.active_editable_fcurve) doesn't have an active keyframe:

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something that only exists as an artifact of the Graph Editor; isn't maintained as a property of an Fcurve; and isn't exported through bpy.  Other examples from the graph editor include the active fcurve and the Enable/disable modifiers "wrench".

There is no concept of an 'active keyframe' in the data.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the insight and confirming my research of the API.